# I can't launch genymotion and I get virtualbox error

Tags: virtualbox, genymotion

I have installed the latest virtualbox genymotion versions and genymotion is not detecting virtualbox.

[image: The error message that I get]

I'm running ubuntu 64 bit. How do I get genymotion to detect virualbox?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and finally solved the problem.

All I had to do was:

```
sudo apt install aptitude
sudo aptitude reinstall virtualbox-dkms
sudo reboot
```

And enable UEFI non secure mode in the boot menu.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Why install aptitude? The usual `apt` (or `apt-get`) can reinstall any package -> `sudo apt install --reinstall <package>`.  And I suggest changing the poorly written last sentence for something like "disable Secure Boot at UEFI settings".